# Can you monitor SQL server to tell exactly what queries it has been running?

Tags: sql-server, multithreading

Can you monitor SQL server to tell exactly what queries it is running?

We have an application that is exhausting the application pool.
A server administrator has sent us a report from Debug Diag `[http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=28bd5941-c458-46f1-b24d-f60151d875a3&displaylang=en][1]` which shows threads running for an hour which doesn't seem possible.
If we could just see what queries the server was actually running we could trace them to our code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have the full version of SQL Server, it has the query profiler (from Management Studio, Tools menu, select "SQL Server Profiler").

Answer (score 0):

```
SHOW PROCESSLIST;
```

or

```
SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;
```

Comment: I believe you'll find that's a MySQL thing.